# Azure WebApp Hotfixes

Tags: azure

Any idea if the guys from Microsoft will automatically install hot fixes for timezone changes like the one mentioned in on this link: 
[Hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3153731)
, or do we need to install them manually. I'm talking about managed Web Apps, not Virtual Machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all hands-free in App Service land - you do no management of those items and the Azure platform will manage updates. I don't know what the frequency of those roll outs is though.